# ListView show item only after refresh

Tags: android, kotlin, listview, android-fragments, android-adapter

I started to learn android and one time I faced with problem like it: In my fragment I have `editText` and `ListView`. I set standard adapter with `ArraList<String>` data and saw that `ListView` show items only after I call the keyboard tapping on `editText`. I tried to find any information about it on many programming websites but I faced failure.

What kind of problem I have?

My .xml file:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".ui.forMainActivity.searchDish.SearchShopFragment"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutCompat"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginVertical="10dp"
        android:weightSum="5">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/for_search_shop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="4" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_search_24" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/for_list_of_categories"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

My fragment file:

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    arrayOfNames = ArrayList()
    db.collection("restaurants")
        .get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
            for (document in documents) {
                arrayOfNames.add(document.data["name"].toString())
            }
        }
    val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search_shop, container, false)
    val adapter = ArrayAdapter(requireContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayOfNames)
    root.findViewById<ListView>(R.id.for_list_of_categories).adapter = adapter
    return root
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update the adapter synchronously with data, as the `addOnSuccessListener` callback get called after you set the adapter, so in below line of code the `arrayOfNames` list is still empty.

```
val adapter = ArrayAdapter(requireContext(), 
                           android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayOfNames)
```

To fix this you need to either:

Set the adapter within the `addOnSuccessListener` callback

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search_shop, container, false)
    arrayOfNames = ArrayList()
    db.collection("restaurants")
        .get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
            for (document in documents) {
                arrayOfNames.add(document.data["name"].toString())
            }
            val adapter = ArrayAdapter(requireContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayOfNames)
            root.findViewById<ListView>(R.id.for_list_of_categories).adapter = adapter
        }
    return root
}
```

Or `adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()` within the callback.

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search_shop, container, false)
    val adapter = ArrayAdapter(requireContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayOfNames)
    root.findViewById<ListView>(R.id.for_list_of_categories).adapter = adapter
    arrayOfNames = ArrayList()
    db.collection("restaurants")
        .get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
            for (document in documents) {
                arrayOfNames.add(document.data["name"].toString())
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    return root
}
```